# Splitting domain name over two hosts

Tags: dns, cpanel, webflow

I want to make the move to Webflow for a client project that require a CMS. I would like some more information about the logistics and best practices of adding domains though.

Say for instance I have a client’s home page and a blog hosted on Webflow and this is accessed by their custom domain. what if I still need to host additonal files, and other pages on a traditional hosting platform with cPanel?

Would it be best to point the www.clientwebsite.com to Webfllow and keep the clientwebsite.com pointing at traditional host with a 301 redirect to the www.clientwebsite.com

I could still have pages on the traditional host for example clientwebsite.com/page.html while being able to add additional pages to Webflow e.g. www.clientwebsite.com/page.html

Basically I want to be able to use the same domain name on both Webflow and traditional hosting with cPanel, I just want to know what the best way to do this is, is there a better way to achieve this, is there anything to be careful of/ or would be considered bad practice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it is the same website, Is there a reason not to host everything in one place (Webflow for example)?

Comment: Hey thanks for response, that would be the ideal scenario but you can only host Webflow produced content in Webflow

Answer (score 0):

Typically, one hostname will resolve to one IP address, so one hosting platform has to be the entry point. If the sites can be logically separated, you should probably just use different hostname (blog.example.com, www.example.com, something.example.com) and point them to different hosting platforms.

If you need to have content from the 2 platforms served under the same hostname, then one platform will be the entry point and there it will have some internal rewrite/proxy rules to fetch and serve content from somewhere else. This is easily doable in all modern webservers (nginx, apache..) but I am not sure your CMS platform will allow it.

Comment: Doesn’t the www. count as a sub domain?

Comment: Nobody is really counting :) (just kidding, you can treat it as subdomain or hostname, it doesn't matter, you can read more here https://superuser.com/questions/887173/what-is-a-hostname-versus-a-computer-name-versus-a-subdomain-versus-www)

Comment: Thanks, so the setup in my original question would be fine to implement?